# Access array from addEventListener

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have added a `addEventListener` to button click event. After clicking button I want to delete global array data.

Now i am not able to pass the array with `this.arrayname`, I'm trying below code. It's deleting the data but not updating the parent array .

Please let me know how to pass parameter to `addEventListener` or how to call function from `addEventListener`, so that I can update the array .
    this.array = deletejson;
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {  for (var i = 0; i < deletejson.length; i++) {
            var cur = deletejson[i];
            if (cur.keywordname == (document.getElementById("keywordname") as HTMLTextAreaElement).value) {
                deletejson.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }}});
complete code:

```
    export class ExtractionConfigurationComponent implements OnInit {
    array = [];
   constructor(private adminWorkflowService:AdminWorkflowService) { }
   ngOnInit() {}
    addedkeywords(data: any){
   btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  //var x = document.getElementById(this.id);
  //x.style.display='none';
  for (var i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
      var cur = this.array[i];
      if (cur.keywordname == (document.getElementById("keywordname") as                HTMLTextAreaElement).value) {
          this.array.splice(i, 1);
          break;
          console.log("after deleting data" +this.array);
          console.log("after deleting data" +JSON.stringify(this.array));}}});}
```

Comment: Please read the formatting questions beside the question editor and make your code readable. Better yet, make it an inline [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: can you give the full script

Comment: In what context is `this.array` being used? In a class?

Comment: @terry,yes its there in class ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the array is stored as `this.array` (it's unclear in what context you are doing this), then you need access to the lexical this in your event listener's callback. This can be done by using arrow functions:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
        var cur = this.array[i];
        if (cur.keywordname == (document.getElementById("keywordname") as HTMLTextAreaElement).value) {
            this.array.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried with above code but its not working , i have updated the code ...